# stubby4node redirect to different port on same host

Tags: node.js, http, redirect, port, stubbing

With stubby4node I am trying to configure a redirect to a different port on the same host.

My problem is that I have no host variable available that I could use to rewrite an absolute url from. I have tried with a relative URL starting with the port, but this does not seems to be http compliant:

```
-   request:
        method: GET
        url: /abc/client/v4/([a-zA-Z]{2,5})/([a-zA-Z]{2})/register/Apple/([a-z0-9\.]*)/([a-fA-F0-9\s]*)

    response:
        status: 302
        headers: 
            Location: :3000/pushRegistration/<%url[3]%>
```

I hoped there was a variable like <%url.host%> that I could read from but I didn't find any in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sending the host header, which isn't really what I wanted - since it requires a client change.